# Why isn't my positioning mixin working in Stylus when it works with Sass?

Tags: css, mixins, stylus

I use a positioning Mixins for aligning my divs to the top or left or center of the page etc, it works fine with SCSS/Sass but for some reason it's behaving very strangely when I try to use Stylus.

If I include one Mixin it works fine but when I add in more Mixins below, it will default to another Mixin.

Example of my Mixin:

```
top()
   position absolute
   margin auto
   top 0
   right 0
   //bottom 0
   left 0
```

[Editable demo of the buggy code](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/XKOGvp?editors=1100)

Some theories:

- It's combining my declarations?
- Stylus can't tell which Mixin I'm calling?

Comment: Why are both `right` and `left` equal to `0` inside of `top()`? Shouldn't `top()` only have `top 0`?

Comment: it's my hackish way of positioning things, if you want something to be aligned to top then you omit bottom, if you want something to align to left you omit right, if you want it to be centered you keep them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the mixin indicator `-`. This should work for you:

```
// this is the mixin I'm calling, it positions the div to the top   
-top()
    position: absolute
    margin: auto
    top: 0
    right: 0
    left: 0

// for some reason the div is defaulting to this mixin instead
-center()
    position: absolute
    margin: auto
    top: 0
    right: 0
    bottom: 0   
    left: 0

// if you comment this block out it will work normally, calling the top() mixin only
-left()
    position: absolute
    margin: auto
    top: 0
    bottom: 0
    left: 0

// my div calling top() 
.block
    -top()  
    background: #345
    width: 100px
    height: 100px
```

Comment: Nope, `-` is not required for a mixin.

Comment: @Panya - Then why does this work now? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akXApX?editors=1100

Comment: because `-left` is not used in `-top` mixin. See my answer below.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. `-left != left`

Comment: I was looking at the examples in "Try Stylus" on their site and it looked like a lot of the mixins all started with `-`. Must be described that way to try and prevent this exact problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is [transparent mixins](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html). You're defining `left()` mixin and using it in the `top()` mixin:

```
left 0 -> left(0)
```

It's a good practice not to use CSS property names as names of mixins in Stylus.

Comment: This also fixed the bug, thanks @Panya - I wish I could checkmark both

Comment: Transparent mixins are the real reason that causes this bug. The answer from @J.Titus is just a workaround :)